# Does AWS lambda guarantee no downtime when updating function to a new version?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

By default, AWS uses the `LATEST` alias for the latest lambda version updated and I assume the below step.

1. Now, `LATEST` alias points version 5.
2. User deploys the new version of the lambda.
3. While deploying the new version, `LATEST` alias still points version 5.
4. When the deploying is complete, Lambda just switches `LATEST` alias to version 6.

Through the steps, lambda seems to have almost 0 downtime.

However, It is just an assumption.

Is there any document explicitly mentioning about the downtime while deploying the new version?
I just want to know how much AWS guarantee downtime while deploying the new version.

I also found similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41729365/what-happens-to-request-in-the-middle-of-an-aws-lambda-update), however not clear for my question.

Answer (score 4):

AWS Lambda uses containers for deployment. If I had to guess, AWS is spinning up Version 6 while Version 5 is still active, then once Version 6 is ready, it applies whatever changes necessary to point traffic to the now live Version 6. The below article mentions somewhat the AWS Lambda container lifecycle:

https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/container-reuse-in-lambda/